# What does it the set $\{x:\sum x_i a_i =b\}$ look like geometrically for given a vector $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The full set I am looking at is $S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x\succcurlyeq 0, x^T \leq 1, 1^Tx=1,\sum_i^nx_ia_i=b_1, \sum_i^nx_ia_i^2=b_2\}$, given that $a_0,a_1,...,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$, and $b_1,b_2\in \mathbb{R}$.

What do the conditions $\sum_i^nx_ia_i=b_1, \sum_i^nx_ia_i^2=b_2$ mean?

I can see that the first conditions, $x\succcurlyeq 0, x^T \leq 1, 1^Tx=1$, define a triangle/simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$, but the next conditions allude me. What does it mean for essentially the dot product of two vectors to be constant? I think that the notation $\sum_i^nx_ia_i=b_1$ is a weird way of defining a hyperplane. But because $a_i,b_1$ are not restricted, then this hyperplane could not intersect with the simplex defined earlier. The sum $\sum_i^nx_ia_i^2=b_2$ is I think a parabolic surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Is this sound reasoning or am I missing something about the conditions $\sum_i^nx_ia_i=b_1, \sum_i^nx_ia_i^2=b_2$?

Comment: $\sum x_i a_i = b$ means an $n-1$ dimensional hyper-plane that is orthogonal to the vector $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. It seems that $a_i, b$ are fixed. Why do you think this hyperplane cannot intersect the simplex? It can, depends on $a_i, b$.

Comment: @PeterFranek, I would think that it either intersects at one value for $a,b$ if the hyper plane is parallel, otherwise there are just some values of $a,b$ that could intersect it with a line.

Comment: @PeterFranek, what are your thoughts on $\sum x_i a_i^2=b_2?

Comment: Unless some very special cases (such as all $a_i$'s are equal, for instance) those two planes are not parallel and their intersection is $n-2$-dimensional.